# Can bootstrapped model data be set with Restangular?

Tags: restangular

The model-data i have set serverside in the HTML:

```
<head>
<script>
  window.GlobalExpress = {
    modelData: { ... },
    collectionData: [ ... ]
  };    
</script>
</head>
```

I wanna be able to initialize the Restangular models with it, the way i was able to, back in the backbone days:

```
var SpecialModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
var aModel = new SpecialModel(GlobalExpress.modelData);


var SpecialCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... });
var aCollection = new SpecialCollection(GlobalExpress.collectionData);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can:

```
var user = Restangular.all('users');
_.extend(user, Restangular.restangularizeCollection(null, objectData, 'users'));
```

[Source](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/190)